# log4j Appender additivity for custom log level

Tags: java, logging

I have a scenario where I have a separate custom level defined XYZLogLevel for logging and I have 2 rolling file appenders where 2nd appender is specifically reserved to log log messages from XYZLogLevel. However the logs are going in both the files which is undesirable.

Note:-

1. Logs are not package specific, so adding additivity for package wont
   work.
2. Everything has to be done through `log4j.properties` file.

Adding LevelRangeFilter to first appender partially resolves it, but
    when I add 3rd appender for another custom level, then I again see
    duplication in 2nd and 3rd appender.

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, F, XYZLOG, LMNLOG

log4j.appender.F=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.F.File=f_log.log
log4j.appender.F.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.F.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.F.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.F.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.appender.XYZLOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.File=xyz_reporting.log
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.threshold=XYZLOG#com.services.domain.xyzlogs.XYZLogLevel
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter    
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.filter.a.LevelToMatch=XYZLOG#com.services.domain.xyzlogs.XYZLogLevel
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.filter.a.AcceptOnMatch=true 
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.XYZLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.LMNLOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.File=lmn_reporting.log
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.threshold=LMNLOG#com.services.domain.lmnlogs.LMNLogLevel
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter    
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.filter.a.LevelToMatch=LMNLOG#com.services.domain.lmnlogs.LMNLogLevel
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.filter.a.AcceptOnMatch=true 
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LMNLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

Maybe this can be solved through `org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter` but somehow I was not able to configure that for properties file. I believe that functionality is only for XML configuration.

Its a very tricky sitution as I dont have the liberty to switch to XML configuration, any help on this would be appreciated guys.
Link and examples would be great as I understand them quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am answering my own question.

First you need to create a logger and set additivity as FALSE.

log4j.logger.XZYLOG=XZYLOG#XYZLOG#com.services.domain.xyzlogs.XYZLogLevel, XYZAPPENDER

log4j.additivity.XZYLOG=false

log4j.logger.LMNLOG=LMNLOG#XYZLOG#com.services.domain.lmnlogs.LMNLogLevel, LMNAPPENDER

log4j.additivity.LMNLOG=false

Then configure the appenders in following way.

log4j.appender.XYZLOGAPPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.XYZLOGAPPENDER.File=xyz_reporting.log
log4j.appender.XYZLOGAPPENDER.threshold=XYZLOG#com.services.domain.xyzlogs.XYZLogLevel
log4j.appender.XYZLOGAPPENDER.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.XYZLOGAPPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.XYZLOGAPPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.XYZLOGAPPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.LMNLOGAPPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LMNLOGAPPENDER.File=lmn_reporting.log
```

log4j.appender.LMNLOGAPPENDER.threshold=LMNLOG#com.services.domain.lmnlogs.LMNLogLevel
    log4j.appender.LMNLOGAPPENDER.MaxFileSize=100KB
    log4j.appender.LMNLOGAPPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.LMNLOGAPPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.LMNLOGAPPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

```
You may or may not need the filter in this case.

Note: I cannot post company code here thats why I modified the solution.
This is to give you general idea how I have solved this problem.
```